# Parsing a .lis file in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I am trying to parse in a .lis file into python to perform further analysis on the data but every time I get the following error,

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='Data.lis' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

I am parsing in the file with the standard command,

```
open(fileName)
```

Is there a certain package I need to install or is my parsing method incorrect?

Comment: You don't show any error (or a [mcve]) and `open` does not perform any parsing, it just opens a file object

Comment: @UnholySheep is correct.  That is not an error; you have opened the file.  Now all you have to do is understand what you want to do with it.  Note that opening is a complete differently challenge from parsing; you have not parsed anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

What you got as an output doesn't appear to be an error, it is just telling you that python opened the file, and you have a file type object now.

Further, the operation you performed only got you part of the way. When reading a file, you need to:

1. Open the file
2. Store it as a variable (usually)
3. Read the variable a line at a time
4. Parse the result of your reading
5. Close the file

I usually start by trying to open the file in a program like [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). That way I can get an idea of what I am trying to parse.

Let's walk through an example:

```
filename = 'myfile.lis'
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

The code above opens the `.lis` file, and then prints the file to the console one line at a time. The `with` statement ensure that the file gets closed after we're done.

However, you could just as well replace the `print()` command with a `parse()` command of your own choosing:

```
def parse(input_line):
    if 'text' in input_line:
        print('I found \'text\' in line \'{}\''.format(input_line))
```

Hopefully that will get you started. If you are able to provide more detail about what the contents of your `.lis` file is, or what you are looking to extract from that file, I'm sure many around here can provide better guidance.